# onsubmit is not calling my function when Enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit, enter

```
<form onsubmit="submit(); return false;" name="text" id="form" method="get">
<input type="feild" style="font-size: 150%;" id="field" name="field" value=""
onSubmit="this.value='';"/>
<input type="button" id="add" style="font-size: 150%;" value=" Add tally to score "/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

If I change "submit();" to "alert('here');" it calls the alert function perfectly.
Why does it not call the submit function?

I want the function to be called when the user presses enter.
http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/JsAr4/

note: The button on the side is for a different purpose, and not part of the problem.
**edit**
More work, trying to follow Christians example has gotten me here http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/MGxNG/

I don't see why this is different than his example!
All I get is "{"error": "Please use POST request"}"
and his works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method onsubmit on input elements.

On fiddle, if you change the type="button" to type="submit" on the input button, then the form is called when you press the button.

**Edit:**

Your problem seems to be two things.

One is that the `submit` is a native method in the browser. If you change the name to eg. `mySubmit` solves the problem.

The second is that JSFiddle put the js code inside a scope. This means that the methods you define will not be available outside that scope. This is resoved by making the method global:

```
window.mySubmit = function () {
    alert('test');
}
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KrooniX/UttWF/

Comment: The button on screen has a different function entirely.
I put '<input type="submit" value="submit" style="visibility:hidden" />'
in there because I saw that in another answer.

Comment: Oups, saw your answer when I posted, are deleting mine.

Comment: I linked to the wrong version
http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/JsAr4/

I do not want the button on the side to call submit();

Comment: Yes, it looks like I've seen on an older fiddle.
If you want to call a method on key press enter, you must either have a separate <FORM> tag or write something js that check if the input key is the enter button.

Comment: Niklas: I would not have minded a som Google Wave technology on StackOverflow so you get the answers before you finish typing them.

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this suggestion.
I put your code in the javascript section, and now it does nothing.

Comment: I also changed it to
<form onsubmit="mysubmit(); return false;"

Comment: More messing around based on your suggestion has gotten to here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kaninepete/VAp6e/

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce outside of jsfiddle, and it feels like it's working as is. Maybe I didn't get the complete code?

This is what I used (even removed the button discussed earlier). This works when pressing Enter in the textbox (tested in FF). Is there something I'm missing?

```
<html>

<head>

<style>
</style>

<script lang="javascript">

var tally = "0";
window.onload = setup;

function setup() {
    drawTally();
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = addScore;
    document.getElementById("form").onSubmit= submit;
}

function addScore() {
    document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('change').innerHTML)+tally;
    tally=0;
}

function submit(){
    alert("it worked!");
}

function drawTally() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('tallyDisp');
    //var tally = 0;
    if (elem && elem.getContext) {
        var context = elem.getContext('2d');
        if (context) {
            context.fillStyle = '#9f9';
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
            context.fillStyle = '#00f';
            context.font = 'bold 100px sans-serif';
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.textBaseline = 'middle';
            context.fillText(tally, 150, 100);
        }
    }
}
setInterval("drawTally();", 60);
</script>


<body>
  <h1>Farkle</h1>
<canvas height="200" width="300" id="tallyDisp">Oops!</canvas>

<form onsubmit="tally=parseInt(tally)+parseInt((text.elements.field.value));
document.text.elements.field.value=''; return false;" id="form" name="text">
    <input type="feild" onsubmit="this.value='';" value="" name="field" id="field" style="font-size: 150%;">

</form>
<p>Your score is <span id="change"> 0</span>!</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that Christian caught the real problem, and that explains why "my" code works as well.